# "Specified cast is not valid" when deleting a row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm having a `Specified cast is not valid` error. Windows form application in C#. I'm trying to delete a row from  `datagridview`.

```
  private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                da.Update(dt);
            }
        }
```

*PS:* `button4` is my deletebutton.

Comment: the code runs at first attempt but after the next attempt this exception appears already. can you please help me with this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Which line do you get the error on? What do you see in the debugger about the objects in question before the error is thrown?

Comment: this line Taekahn: "da.Update(dt)"

Comment: What are `da` and `dt`? I see neither defined in your code.

Comment: its dataadapter (da) and datatable (dt). sorry.

Comment: Show a code how `datatable` is filled with data. Seems like some column of datatable contain value of type which cannot be converted to the corresponding database type. For example `Int32` to `SMALLINT`. And please update a question rather then writing more useful information in the comments